# Creating an organized report as a pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, bitmap, itext

I am trying to create a report from my windows form as a pdf, So i used the **itextsharp library** to create the pdf like that:

```
Document reportaspdf = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(reportaspdf, new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
reportaspdf.Open();

#region Design border
var content = writer.DirectContent;
var pageBorderRect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(reportaspdf.PageSize);
pageBorderRect.Left += reportaspdf.LeftMargin;
pageBorderRect.Right -= reportaspdf.RightMargin;
pageBorderRect.Top -= reportaspdf.TopMargin;
pageBorderRect.Bottom += reportaspdf.BottomMargin;
content.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
content.Rectangle(pageBorderRect.Left, pageBorderRect.Bottom, pageBorderRect.Width, pageBorderRect.Height);
content.Stroke();
#endregion

//Add Text
var TitleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Segoe UI", 50.0f, BaseColor.BLACK);
var SubtitleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Segoe UI", 30.0f, BaseColor.BLACK);
var DescribtionFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Segoe UI", 20.0f, BaseColor.ORANGE);

var p1 = new Paragraph("Final Report", TitleFont);
p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
reportaspdf.Add(new Paragraph(p1));
#region add originalimg
var Describitiontext = new Paragraph("Original Image", DescribtionFont);
Describitiontext.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
Describitiontext.SpacingBefore = 20;
reportaspdf.Add(new Paragraph(Describitiontext));

iTextSharp.text.Image orignamIMG = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(OrignalImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
orignamIMG.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
reportaspdf.Add(orignamIMG);
#endregion
```

Until now everything is perfect but after adding another images and text they have been added under the previous images but i want to structure my report as every 2 image at the same level and so on

**So, How can i added more than one item at the same level ?**

The second thing is 
when i take a screen capture from panel, the width of image became larger than the document width so i use this function to resize the image before adding it to the pdf document but it's resolution become so poor,

**So, How can i resize image without loosing the quality ?**

```
public Bitmap Resizeimage(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    // Get the image's original width and height
    int originalWidth = image.Width;
    int originalHeight = image.Height;

    // To preserve the aspect ratio
    float ratioX = (float)maxWidth / (float)originalWidth;
    float ratioY = (float)maxHeight / (float)originalHeight;
    ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    // New width and height based on aspect ratio
    int newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * ratio);
    int newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * ratio);

    // Convert other formats (including CMYK) to RGB.
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    // Draws the image in the specified size with quality mode set to HighQuality
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest you ask the 2nd question in another post, which makes the questions easier to answer and follow, you can add links in the questions to reference each other to provide context.